# How to preserve Integer in PHP CURL request

Tags: php, http, curl, post

I'm working with an API and when I send the POST request to them they throw a warning that one of the fields in the array has to be type Integer, not a String.

My CURL setup is like this:

```
$post_fields = array(
            'data_source_uuid' => $uuid,
            'name' => 'TestPlan',
            'interval_count' => 1,
            'interval_unit' => 'month',
            'external_id' => 'Eur_fees'
        );
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $api_key
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  $post_fields, 
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => 'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close( $curl );
```

When I send this to another URL on my localhost and var_dump it I get this:

```
    string(253) "array(5) {
          ["data_source_uuid"]=>
          string(39) "uuid"
          ["name"]=>
          string(8) "TestPlan"
          ["interval_count"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["interval_unit"]=>
          string(5) "month"
          ["external_id"]=>
          string(8) "Eur_fees"
        }"
```

The problem here is interval_count is a String not an Integer. If I var_dump before using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS it is an Integer so something in the CURL part is changing it but I'm not sure what.

The API is for a website called chartmogul.com

Comment: https://secure.php.net/language.types.type-juggling#language.types.typecasting

Comment: That doesn't work as it is an Int before the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, it's not being preserved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill from ChartMogul here. You would need to encode your data with `json_encode($data)`. Please also ensure that your data source UUID, account secret key and account token are correct. The following request works for me:

```
<?php 

// account variables
$ds_uuid = "DATA_SOURCE_UUID";
$token = 'API_TOKEN';
$password = 'SECRET_KEY';

// request url
$baseurl='https://api.chartmogul.com/v1/';
$url=$baseurl.'import/plans';

// data to be posted
$post_fields = array(
            'data_source_uuid' => "$ds_uuid",
            'name' => 'A plan',
            'interval_count' => 1,
            'interval_unit' => 'month',
            'external_id' => 'eur_fees'
        );

// encode json data
$data = json_encode($post_fields);

// initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$token:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
);

// make the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// decode the result
$json = json_decode($result, true);

// print the result
print $json;

curl_close($ch);
?>`enter code here`
```

Comment: By the way, ChartMogul now has a PHP client library that you can use: https://github.com/chartmogul/chartmogul-php.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation says here (https://dev.chartmogul.com/docs/import-plan), you have to send JSON data.

Instead of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  $post_fields`, you should use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  json_encode($post_fields)`

EDIT : Also, the documentation says that you have to send 5 parameters, you forgot one required named "data_source_uuid", a string that contains the ChartMogul UUID of the data source for this subscription plan.

Comment: That doesn't work. When I do that the message back is "error":"The property '#/' did not contain a required property of 'data_source_uuid'". I think that is because CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS does automatic urlencoding

Comment: Yes because you forgot to send "data_source_uuid" parameter (that shoud contain the ChartMogul UUID of the data source for this subscription plan).

Comment: Nope. I left that out of my example but when I put that in the array before your suggestion it doesn't work. I'll update my question to include that now.

Comment: Can you show the json_encode of your $post_fields please ? (don't forget to occult your uuid)

Comment: {"data_source_uuid":"uuid_xyz","name":"TestPlan","interval_count":1, "interval_unit":"month","external_id":"Eur_fees"}   That is from before I use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. When I echo it just after the curl_exec line it's this: {"data_source_uuid":"uuid_xyz","name":"TestPlan","interval_count": "1","interval_unit":"month", "external_id":"Eur_fees"}

Comment: Can you add this option in your curl_setopt_array `CURLOPT_POST => true` and test again ? If not working, can you show the url you are using (should be "https://api.chartmogul.com/v1/import/plans")

Comment: Same result with that line included. $url = 'https://api.chartmogul.com/v1/import/plans'; I have the https in there but when I save the comment it's removed

Comment: Have you tried with the CLI example the documentation provide to see if any difference ?